# How to play Youtube video in Android application?

Tags: android, youtube-api

How can I configure Youtube video player API for my Android applicarion to play Youtube video on video view or Surface view.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no "you tube video player API" in Android.

Answer (score 0):

API provides only 3gp rtsp links or embed player

Comment: please explain your answers in more detail